# how can i create archives for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

the WordPress framework allows to build different archive templates for each of your custom post type by e.g:

```
archive-event.php
taxonomy-event_category.php
```

is it possible to create author and date archive for custom post type by doing the following:

```
author-event.php
date-event.php
```

if this is not possible, can anyone advise how i can go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think these links will help answer your question and get you started:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

The gist of it is that you can in fact make an `author-event.php` however `date-event.php` does not get checked because the template hierarchy dictates that it uses `date.php`, `archive.php`, or `index.php`.

One solution is to use conditional tags such as `is_author()` or `is_date()`. If you do, keep in mind that you'll have to have a common `archive.php` and decide which template you really want to use by using conditional tags.